# Does LibGDX share preferences with Android API?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Can I get a value from LibGDX preferences like this:

```
Preferences preferences = Gdx.app.getPreferences("someName");
int value = preferences.getInteger("intValue");
```

And then in the same project, in a different activity, do this:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("someName",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int value = preferences.getInt("intValue",0);
```

So assuming there is a value already stored, would both methods retrieve the same value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right in assuming that both codesnippets do the same thing.
Checking the implementation for the Android backend, they show that the same Android methods are being called.

```
@Override
public Preferences getPreferences (String name) {
    return new AndroidPreferences(getSharedPreferences(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-android/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidApplication.java#L373-L376)

and

```
@Override
public int getInteger (String key) {
    return sharedPrefs.getInt(key, 0);
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-android/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidPreferences.java#L89-L92)